# Can a SQL query provide a value that ColdFusion can use?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I'm currently building a member survey, where each member gets a unique link that they use to access the survey. Once they access it and submit the survey they can no longer use the link. Here is what I have so far:

```
<cfquery name="SurveyTaken" maxrows="1" datasource="#APPLICATION.DATASOURCE#">
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AllMembers WHERE me_number = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.em#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char">)
        SELECT * FROM MemberSurvey         
        WHERE me_number = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.em#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char"> 
</cfquery>

<cfif SurveyTaken.recordcount eq 1>

    <p>We are sorry but it seems that you have already taken the survey. This link has been used and is no longer valid.</p> 

<cfelseif SurveyTaken.recordcount eq 0>
    <cfquery name="SurveyIndividual" maxrows="1" datasource="#APPLICATION.DATASOURCE#">        
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    AllMembers         
        WHERE   me_number = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.em#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char"> 
    </cfquery>

    <cfform action="" method="post" id="addCommentForm" onsubmit="return submit_form()">
    .... etc...
</cfif>
```

Basically I want my SQL query to check first if the member ID is valid, and then in another table check if the member id has already been submited. Right now it works if a valid member id is posted in the URL because it passes the "IF" part, but if the IF part is not passed, no query is run, so my .recordcount solution doesn't work. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here since I don't know your exact schema.

Assuming that you have a primary (or at least unique) key in the membersurvey table named `membersurvey_id`...

```
SELECT  m.me_number, ISNULL(s.membersurvey_id,0) AS membersurvey_id
FROM allmembers m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN membersurvey s ON m.me_number = s.me_number
WHERE m.me_number = <cfqueryparam value="#url.em" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char">
```

A recordcount > 0 means that the url.em was valid. If the recordcount > 0, then a membersurvey_id > 0 means that the survey has already been filled out.

Note that I used MSSQL's `ISNULL` function. You didn't specify exactly which type of database you're using, so you may need to use a more package-specific version of that function.

Comment: How do I reference membersurvey_ID in an cfif statement?

Comment: <cfif SurveyTaken.membersurvey_id eq [something]>

Comment: The same as any other query column. ie `<cfif queryName.membersurvey_id gt 0> survey found. do something</cfif>`

Comment: or possibly include the row number if you're returning more than one row and you're not in a loop where you specified the query.  <cfif SurveyTaken.membersurvey_id[1...n] eq [something]>

Comment: Just be sure to check the `query.recordCount` first to verify the row number exists.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're recording something when the survey is completed to invalidate the id? Something like `set idValid = 0`.

You probably want to do something more like

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    MemberSurvey         
WHERE me_number = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.em#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char"> 
and idValid is NULL
```

Since that will return 0 records with an fake ID or a good ID that has done the survey, you'll need to reverse your .recordCount values in your cfif.

OR if you're just deleting the ID from your table, simply use

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    MemberSurvey         
WHERE me_number = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.em#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char">
```

You'll still need to reverse your .recordCounts in your cfif.

Comment: This doesn't work because the me_number is stored in a different table. The survey table is blank at this point, and is only populated once a survey is filled out.

Comment: then the premise of phantom42's answer is more suited.